# What values I should set in twitter bootstrap for a fixed 960px layout?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I'm using twitter bootstrap with less cloned from github. I want to set grid width variables because I need a 960px fixed layout. Default values for 940px width are:

```
@gridColumns:             12;
@gridColumnWidth:         60px;
@gridGutterWidth:         20px;
```

What values I should set for a fixed 960px layout?

I tried with this, but result was 950px:

```
@gridColumns:             12;
@gridColumnWidth:         70px;
@gridGutterWidth:         10px;
```

Comment: Have you seen that those 3 vars can be set when you do a custom download? http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html

Comment: What's exactly your question? How to change these values? How to calculate the values you need?

Comment: @MereDevelopment: The OP is using LESS, there's no need for a custom download - he can configure it himself with LESS. smoreno: Just break out the caclulator, remember that there is always one less gutter than the total # of columns.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Solve the equation

You need to find a solution(s) for [the equasion](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+n%2ac+%2B+%28n+-+1%29%2ag+%3D+960%2C+n+%3D+12%2C+c+%3E+g%2C+g+%3E+0+over+integers). One of them is:

```
@gridColumns:             12;
@gridColumnWidth:         69px;
@gridGutterWidth:         12px;
```

another one:

```
@gridColumns:             12;
@gridColumnWidth:         58px;
@gridGutterWidth:         24px;
```

### But use default

Bootstrap [was designed for 960px](http://bootstrapdocs.com/v1.0.0/docs/#grid-system) width, it just doesn't specify additional margin/padding on the sides:

```
| ------------------------------ 960px width ---------------------------------- |
10px left margin | ------------- 940px container ------------ | 10px right margin
```

So I suggest you to use the default values, if you are targeting 960px.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!. My design has not right/left margins, so I want to use 960px for real content without margins.

Answer (score 1):

You could always make a 960px container and use fluid.

Comment: You should add some code with that example, just to complement a bit more your answer.