# Values to set in Bootstrap for custom span and gutter width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I am trying to create a fixed layout using bootstrap. I want the value of span3 = 278px and the gutter width = 12px; The total width of layout should be around 1142px

I have tried this http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/customize.html tool to get the solution but its not giving me the result, may be because I am not providing the right values.

Could you please tell me what should be the values of the following to achieve the result?

```
@gridColumns =  ?
@gridColumnWidth = ?
@gridGutterWidth  = ?   
@gridColumnWidth1200 = ?
@gridGutterWidth1200 = ?
@gridColumnWidth768 = ?
@gridGutterWidth768 = ?
```

I have checked this https://stackoverflow.com/a/12286772/1209690 but its not helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@gridColumns =  12
@gridColumnWidth = 92
@gridGutterWidth  = 12
```

Would be your setup, while

```
@gridColumnWidth1200 = ?
@gridGutterWidth1200 = ?
@gridColumnWidth768 = ?
@gridGutterWidth768 = ?
```

are used for setting a wider layout on bigger/smaller resolutions than the current "standard", so you will have to adjust your layout for that.

If you need it just redesign the layout you want to have on that screen size and recalculate the span3 : `spanX / X = @gridColumnWidth`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But 278/3 = 92 and but the value of span3 I am getting is 270px :) thanks

Comment: its working now, I had to remove the codes for responsiveness. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @black_belt - also check out the less source if you do alot of modifications to the default bootstrap - https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases/tag/v2.3.2 - less/variables.less contains the setting you see on the customize page - except that you can edit them faster in your project - no need to download again.